# Difficulty in parsing JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to develop a flutter app and I am finding it difficult to parse this JSON I have seen posts regarding this but I am finding it difficult to parse this. Help a beginner out! Here is the JSON link " https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json "
I am simply using:

```
Future getJsonDistrictData() async {
var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url1));
var converttojson1 = json.decode(response.body);

setState(() {
  myData= converttojson1;
});
}
Text("${myData['Kerala']['districtData']['Thrissur']['confirmed']}")
```

But this would mean I have to write the same line for every district confirmed cases.
How should I proceed?

Comment: But how are you trying to parse it at the moment? What problem are you facing?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow mate, please add your code when posting a question, what you have tried.

Comment: I have just added the code that I was trying.

Comment: try this https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable. it will be helpful to generate your models from/to json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the following example of an implementation you can use the parse the data from the URL in your question.

It can be simplified if you don't need the `lastUpdatedTime` and `delta_confirmed` since it looks like this is always the empty String and zero in the API.

```
import 'dart:convert';

class State {
  final Map<String, DistrictData> districts = {};

  State.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    for (final district in json['districtData'].keys) {
      districts[district as String] =
          DistrictData.fromJson(json['districtData'][district]);
    }
  }

  @override
  String toString() => districts.toString();
}

class DistrictData {
  final int confirmed;
  final DateTime lastUpdatedTime;
  final int delta_confirmed;

  DistrictData(this.confirmed, this.lastUpdatedTime, this.delta_confirmed);

  factory DistrictData.fromJson(dynamic json) => DistrictData(
      json['confirmed'] as int,
      (json['lastupdatedtime'].isEmpty as bool)
          ? null
          : (DateTime.parse(json['lastupdatedtime'] as String)),
      json['delta']['confirmed'] as int);

  @override
  String toString() =>
      '{ confirmed: $confirmed, lastUpdatedTime: $lastUpdatedTime, delta_confirmed: $delta_confirmed }';
}

void main() {
  final states = json.decode(input).map(
          (String key, dynamic value) => MapEntry(key, State.fromJson(value)))
      as Map<String, State>;
  states.forEach((key, value) => print('$key : $value'));
  /*
  Kerala : {Thrissur: { confirmed: 13, lastUpdatedTime: null, delta_confirmed: 0 }, Alappuzha: { confirmed: 5, lastUpdatedTime: null, delta_confirmed: 0 }}
  Delhi : {East Delhi: { confirmed: 1, lastUpdatedTime: null, delta_confirmed: 0 }}
  */
}

const input = '''
{
  "Kerala": {
    "districtData": {
      "Thrissur": {
        "confirmed": 13,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      },
      "Alappuzha": {
        "confirmed": 5,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Delhi": {
    "districtData": {
      "East Delhi": {
        "confirmed": 1,
        "lastupdatedtime": "",
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
''';
```

Comment: This looks great. How would I go about looping through district confirmed cases to display it in a Text widget?

Comment: That sounds more like a new question. You question was about how to parse the JSON input you gave us. I am not a Flutter programmer so I have no clue about Text widgets. About the question of looping, can you give an example of how you want the results? Do you just need a Map where the key is district and value is confirmed cases? You don't care about the states? Do you know if there are multiple states with same district names?

Answer (score -1):

Copy your JSON in this link(https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) and get model Class.

Example: [image]

For example your Model Class Name is CovidModel. As you get response from network call, pass data to you model class and get object like this:

```
CovidModel _covidModel = CovidModel.fromJson(response.data);
```

now you can use _covidModel to get inner objects and show result in app page.

Comment: I need to say the code generated by that generator is horrible and should never be used to generate production code. It looks like instead of using Map's to represent... maps? it will instead always use normal variables to represent each key. The problem with the way the classes is generated is that they are dependent on you are going to parse nearly the exact same JSON. This is fine for some things but a lot of times the output from the Web API are going to be some kind of dynamic or you want to iterate over the keys. It is not easy to auto generate classes from JSON results but this is wrong

Comment: You can also try normal JSON2DART plugin in Android Studio to convert. But you can get result fast and later can fix rather than writing that long model class.

Comment: This is my point. The problem with this kind of plugin solutions is you are going to think you need to "writing that long model class". No, the model for this data is extremely easy to define manually and a lot shorter than this auto generated garbage that the web page makes. Take a look at my implementation: https://gist.github.com/julemand101/60eaadd71979f7720ecc833015828509 . Also, this code are something you can actually use to iterate over the data.